# Access Python virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

Is there a way I can access a python virtual environment created by another user on an Ubuntu machine ?

Thanks!

Comment: A virtual environment is just a set of files and directories. If you can access those, you can use the virtualenv.

Comment: Yes, you can access the directory where the virtual env was installed. Probably, you will find these folders in that directory `bin`, `feat`, `include`, and `lib`

Comment: I actually can access the venv files, but how can I work on it, `workon venv_name` returns `ERROR: Environment 'venv_name' does not exist. Create it with 'mkvirtualenv venv_name'.`

Comment: But `workon` is a command from virtualenvwrapper and is set to look in your own directories, so of course it won't see someone else's. That doesn't stop you activating the virtualenv directly via its `bin/activate` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I get it to work using the following command with different user,

`$ . env_name/bin/activate`

note that I needed to grant write & execute rights on the venv files to the current user.